# Should CORS be aware of endpoints method on preflight response?

Tags: php, symfony, cors, websecurity, nelmiocorsbundle

I have a REST API backed with Symfony 4.3 and NelmioCorsBundle for the CORS. I would like to understand if by definition/best practice, it's correct that my security team requires me to respond `OPTIONS` requests indicating methods list (`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) *only* with the methods that *actually are meant* to be used with the particular requested endpoint, instead of a complete list that are used by my entire API.

There's some documentation that clearly clarifies what is correct? So that it is not subject to different interpretations about how.

The vast majority of tutorials and resources like MDN website, gives examples including all the methods (`GET`, `PUT`, `PATCH`...) but never clarifies that. The NelmioCorsBundle doesn't give us any way to take from routes definition. It's for single configuration only.

Answer (score 0):

The [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/), which is the de facto specification for CORS, makes no prescription about this:

> Ultimately server developers have a lot of freedom in how they handle HTTP responses and these tactics can differ between the response to the CORS-preflight request and the CORS request that follows it [...]

In practice, different CORS middleware libraries do different things. Some (like [rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors)) only reflect the one method, whereas others (like [Express's CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)) always list all the allowed methods.

---

You could argue that always listing all the methods allowed by your CORS configuration in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header is "safer":

- On the one hand, you have to pay a small price in terms of bandwidth, because at most one of the methods listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header is necessary for CORS preflight to succeed.
- On the other hand, it provides attackers no incentive to [send additional probing requests](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2022-08-04-scraping-the-bottom-of-the-cors-barrel-part1/#broaden-your-search-for-allowed-origins) meant to determine which methods your CORS configuration allows.

If you're worried about revealing too much about other endpoints, you should be able to apply different CORS configurations to different endpoints.